# Android - Custom view, not drawing correctly

Tags: android, canvas, ondraw

I'm a little bit in stuck.

I try to create a custom view like a table! But the onDraw method is only drawing the first cell/rectangle.

This is my view:

```
public class CustomView extends View {


    private static int ROWS = 8;
    private static int COLS = 8;

    final Paint p = new Paint();

    public CustomView(Context context) {
        super(context);

        p.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawColor(Color.RED);

        float width = getWidth();
        float height = getHeight();
        float cellWidth = width/COLS;
        float cellHeight = height/ROWS;

        for(float row = 0; row<ROWS; row++) {
            for(float col = 0; col<COLS; col++) {
                RectF cell = new RectF( (cellWidth*col), (cellHeight*row), cellWidth, cellHeight);
                canvas.drawRect(cell, p);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

My XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#000000"
    tools:context="com.biegertfunk.qlocktwo.Act_Main">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/centerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

My activity:

```
public class Act_Main extends AppCompatActivity {


//views
public CustomView mainView;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.act_main);

    int size = getSize();

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(size, size);
    layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);


    RelativeLayout mainLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.centerView);

    mainView = new CustomView(this);

    mainLayout.addView(mainView, layoutParams);

}

private int getSize() {
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);
    int width = size.x;
    int height = size.y;

    if(width>height) {
        return height;
    } else {
        return width;
    }
}

}
```

But the result shows only one rectangle:

[image]

Comment: post your xml also

Comment: Added some more informations, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your calculation of `cell` inside `onDraw()` is wrong. Try it this way:

```
RectF cell = new RectF( 
    (cellWidth*col), (cellHeight*row), 
    (cellWidth*col)+cellWidth, (cellHeight*row)+cellHeight
);
```

The constructor of `RectF` is

```
RectF(float left, float top, float right, float bottom)
```

**not**

```
RectF(float left, float top, float width, float height) // WRONG
```

See documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/RectF.html).

Answer (score 0):

Order of parameters passed in the method `RectF` is not correct. As you can see in the documentation of this method in [RectF documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/RectF.html)
You will see that order of the argument is `left`,`top`,`right` and `bottom` respectively. Moreover your left argument must be less than or equals to right argument, which might not be seen your code.

Answer (score -1):

Add The Code

```
invalidate();
```

To

```
for(float row = 0; row<ROWS; row++) {
        for(float col = 0; col<COLS; col++) {
            RectF cell = new RectF( (cellWidth*col), (cellHeight*row), cellWidth, cellHeight);
            canvas.drawRect(cell, p);
            invalidate();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Ouch - calling `invalidate()` in `onDraw()` will result in an infinite loop. You should never call `invalidate()` there...